# viso2_ros demo.launch

Tags: ros, visual-odometry, yaml, viso2-ros, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying out viso2_ros (http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros?distro=fuerte) by running the demo.launch file that was included.  However, it requires a disparity_params.yaml for the stereo_image_proc node.  I don't see an example of what is inside the disparity_params.yaml.  I tried just putting in a camera calibration parameters.  But that does not seem right.

Output from the terminal:

aaron@AntaresL:~/Desktop/DRC/ROS_Examples/viso2-fuerte/viso2_ros/launch$ roslaunch viso2_ros demo.launch
... logging to /home/aaron/.ros/log/6948e56a-ae8e-11e2-b858-180373ea7946/roslaunch-AntaresL-6453.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 12, column 57

What is needed in the disparity_params.yaml to make this program work?  Could someone show an example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61611/viso2_ros-demo.launch/) by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi astaranowicz,

our wrapper uses the same params than the libviso2 library, which you can find [here](http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libviso2.html). However, if you prefer to start with our default params, they were [inside a comment](https://github.com/srv/viso2/issues/6#issuecomment-14390591) in an issue, they are:

```
prefilter_size: 9
prefilter_cap: 31
correlation_window_size: 17
min_disparity: 20
disparity_range: 96
uniqueness_ratio: 10
texture_threshold: 10 
speckle_size: 200
speckle_range: 4
```

These parameter depend on the stereo camera and the environment (texture, light) you have there. Check the parameters [in the ROS wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros?distro=fuerte#Parameters) for more information. If you have any other question, please feel free to ask, but with the parameters it's best to experiment.

Have fun!

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on 2013-05-15**:
Thank you for the help.  I also noticed that the wrapper doesn't pass any other parameters besides the camera parameters (such as focal length and principal point).  How do you pass the other parameters for the matcher and the bucketing?

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-05-15**:
All parameters listed on http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros can be normally set through rosparam, e.g. as  tag in launch files. This is the code fragment where the paramaters are read: http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/viso2_ros/html/odometry__params_8h_source.html

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on 2013-05-20**:
Thanks for that.  I'll try it out.